# Can't launch tritonserver using container

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia-docker, tritonserver

After, i run:
docker run --gpus=all -it --shm-size=256m --rm -p8000:8000 -p8001:8001 -p8002:8002 -v $(pwd)/model_repository:/models nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:22.12-py3

in terminal, I encountered the following error:

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.

I don't know how to fix it.
Help me. Thanks.

I've tried searching online and tried a few methods, but it didn't work. I hope someone can help me solve this issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.